# Error in scikit-neuralnetwork classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am using the `Python(2.7.6)` on `ubuntu(14.04.2 LTS), numpy(1.11.3)` and `scikit-learn version(0.18.1)`. But it throws the following exception. 
Here is the [link](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide_model.html#classification) of official document.

```
nn = Classifier(
    layers=[
        Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
        Layer("Softmax")],
    learning_rate=0.001,
    n_iter=25)
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LeadScore.py", line 19, in <module>
    Layer("Maxout", units=100, pieces=2),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pieces'
```

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: i never used this lib)

- (1) scikit-neuralnetwork has not much to do with scikit-learn, so you should probably mention the version of scikit-neuralnetwork which you are using.
- (2) According to [this](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/142) and [this](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/124) Maxout was removed from the library. If you search for `pieces` or `maxout` within the project-sources [search-link](https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=maxout) no code is found!
- (3) The basic problem here seems to be a mismatch between the example and your version. Maybe there was a version with maxout, but without the parameter pieces. I don't know.
- (4) My opinion: this library/project does not seem that active anymore (at least compared to keras and co.) and while using Pybrain in the past (dead), it seems it's using Lasange (somewhat a dying project too) now. Together with these mismatches between examples and code this would give me a lot of headaches and i would switch libraries.